# RTS-style game camera encoded in Model matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix

I am working with OpenGL 4.0 and I'm trying to write a game camera which has two properties. "Angle of attack" and "Rotation"

I am trying to construct a camera very similar to other RTS games such as Warcraft 3, or Starcraft II where the camera (by default) is facing the ground at a fairly steep angle.

I'm using some support code which acts very similar to the older opengl glTranslatef, glRotatef
My current attempt looks like this:

```
shaders->Model.Translate(-cameraPosition.x,-cameraPosition.y,-cameraPosition.z);
//Apply rotation
//shaders->Model.Rotate(rotation/M_PI*180.0f,0,0,1);

//Apply AOA
float aX = cos(2*3.141592 - rotation - 3.141592/2.0);
float aY = sin(2*3.141592 - rotation - 3.141592/2.0);
shaders->Model.Rotate(90.0f-(float)angleOfAttack/M_PI*180.0f,aY,aX,0);
```

After that point the ground is drawn as a rectangle from (0,0,0) to (width,height,0)
This attempt is mostly functional except when the y increases the ground gets further away. I'm not sure what is causing this, but I assume it has to do with this code because when I set AOA to 90 (so the camera is pointing directly down) it doesn't happen.

Note: I am using the model matrix instead of the view matrix to handle the camera's movements out of necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Silly question I guess.
The trick was to do the X,Y translation after the rotation, not before

```
//Apply translation
shaders->Model.Translate(0,0,-cameraPosition.z);
//Apply rotation
//shaders->Model.Rotate(rotation/M_PI*180.0f,0,0,1);

//Apply AOA
float aX = cos(2*3.141592 - rotation - 3.141592/2.0);
float aY = sin(2*3.141592 - rotation - 3.141592/2.0);
shaders->Model.Rotate(90.0f-(float)angleOfAttack/M_PI*180.0f,aY,aX,0);

shaders->Model.Translate(-cameraPosition.x,-cameraPosition.y,0);
```